combining nodes
I made two different textures on my model (it's gonna be different kinds of freckles in different colours.
But when I combine the nodes, one of the freckles is more visible than the other. Is there any way to combine these nodes, without losing their visibility?


For clarification:
I made 2 different skin textures. When I combine them and set the factor to 0.500, then both textures come through not fully visible, like if I were to only link one of them.


Textures mixed. They arent as visible like they are when they're not mixed. I want them to be mixed but fully visible:


What do you mean by "more visible" ? If you set your Mix to 0.5, you get the middle range color between the two (contributing each for 50% of the result).

pls make clear how it looks now (image) + how you want it to look like (another image). thx.

Hello maybe explain what you're trying to do and we will propose a solution

I'm not 100% on this, but I think you want 3 mix nodes.
Mix node one is your chosen freckle colour, and anything else in B (black in this screenshot). With that freckle as the factor.
Mix node two is the other freckle's chosen colour in A, and mix node 1 in B, using the other freckle texture as the factor.
Finally mix THOSE two mix nodes, into the A and B of a third one, and use the multiplied textures of both freckles for the factor like this:


I hope this is what you meant?

If you're going to post an answer please embed your images in the answer rather than just the links to them. This means that they will always be available if anyone wants to see your answer in future. See How to upload an image to a post.
